# Multiprocessing with a while loop and different arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to loop every second between two datetimes and call a function passing in the current datetime value. I want to split the workload so it doesn't take as long. The 'get_reading' function raises a KeyError if it cannot get a reading with the datetime passed. When I run this, it still produces the error. What am I doing wrong?

```
sdatetime = datetime.datetime(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, fromHour, fromMinute, fromSecond)   # start date
edatetime = datetime.datetime(upToYear, upToMonth, upToDay, upToHour, upToMinute, upToSecond)   # end date

procs = []
proc = Process(target=get_reading)  # instantiating without any argument
procs.append(proc)
proc.start()

while sdatetime <= edatetime:
    print ('Doing something at', sdatetime)
    try:
        proc = Process(target=get_reading, args=(sdatetime,))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()
        # complete the processes
        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()
    except KeyError as e:
        #Do nothing
        pass
    sdatetime += timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: where is `get_reading()` ? What arguments doies it expect? If you need run without arguments then send some fake argument - ie. None - and check `None` in process to make something different.

Comment: it better when you at least display errro - `except KeyError as e: print(e)` - because you can know that there was problem.

Comment: Without seeing `get_reading()` and the error, this is a very incomplete question.